# What's a good general approach for apps like pulse, youtube, NYTimes, etc? Use UIWebView or something else?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, youtube

That may seem like a broad question, but I'm talking specifically here about apps that display a lot of content (image plus some text) pulled from the net in separate cells, rows, etc. And where each of those cells can get loaded asynchronously (independently from all the others).

So for example, for iOS, is it too inefficient to use uiwebview for each of these cells? It seems like this would be a simple approach, but I'm not sure about the performance. "Pulse" has a bunch of cells on the page at one time, and on iPad this could really get to a large number. Is it better to do this using lower level techniques, or is using UIWebView a decent choice?

Update:Clarification-->
Just to clarify, I understand that the typical approach is to use UITableView and then create table cells to hold and show the data (although the "Pulse" UI may be more involved). What I'm getting at here is if those UITableViewCells could hold UIWebViews? So instead of putting a UIImageView and a UITextView in each cell and so forth, if it makes sense to just put UIWebViews there instead, and give them URLs (could pass a param to indicated the row) to load as cellForRowAtIndexPath is called or something.

Comment: I believe they use UIListView and just customize the cells. If you're going to do it using UIWebView, then you may as well make a website.

Comment: Right, but what do you put in the cells. I guess what I'm asking is if it makes any sense at all to put UIWebViews in the cells.

Comment: You would add child views in the cells. For example, you could create a UIView which then adds some label views, image views, button(s), and then when you're done populating the UIView with whatever you need, you'd add it to the cell. Does that make sense?

Comment: @xil3->Right, I understand that approach. Please see the question clarification I put in above. I want to know if having UIWebViews in each cell makes sense in this case. Look at youtube or NY times or pulse. Each cell loads independently and serves the sole purpose of displaying a bit of content and allowing the user to click it to get to a more detailed page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use UIWebViews with UITableViews like that. There are far too many moving parts for a UITableView!

I wrote the NYTimes iPhone app while I worked there. I only ever used a UIwebView to display article content. This is because NYT articles and log post layout is extremely complicated and impracticle to replicate programmatically. (I did override some of the CSS in app)

The UITableView is a super high performance implementation for butter smooth high speed scrolling. UIWebViews are the opposite of that: heavy, slow and memory intensive. In fact web views actually run internal virtual machines and threads (for JavaScript, rendering, etc).

Keep in mind that table view cells are recycled very aggressively. The instant a cell scrolls off screen bottom it will, in gneral, be immediately reconfigured for use as the new cell that scrolls in from the top.

With a UITableView, you need to create VERY highly optimized custom UITableViewCells. The data displayed in the cells should be cached aggressively by you so that you don't need to recompute it or perform intensive layout calculations. Uncacheable information such as remote images should be  loaded asynchronously (which might mean they show up much later).

On caching:
The NYT apps have a high performance caching system for images. The trick is to request the imge data as soon as its "needed", but to also preempt downloading images which were needed a second ago, but no longer. You also don't want to cancel partially downloaded images because that wastes the already consumed bandwidth.  Check out NSOperationQueue. It has most of the levers needed to build such a system.

Another note: consider building a web app if your project may also be accessed via web or an android app.

Comment: Thanks @adam kalpan .. nicely explained

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you talk about the YouTube app, its not UIWebview. The common and better approach is to use UITableViews along with the custom UITableCells. As far as asynchronous loading of images is the concern, we implement "Lazy Loading" mechanism. And in this way, we are able to keep the performance benefit of native UIView intact. Whereas, in UIWebView, you would need to design the iphone based webpages which will cost you learn about Dashcode tool, or may be someother opensource css library, etc.

In short, UITableView, with Custom UITableCells, along with Lazy Loading Mechanism (achieved by some Threading Techniques) will do all the Magic for you.

Hope this answer will give you some better idea....

Comment: Thanks, I guess what I'm really asking here is if it works at all to use UIWebViews in each of the UITableCells or if that is horribly inefficient because there is too much processing overhead with UIWebViews. The Lazy Loading technique you describe (using I assume NSURLRequest, etc) makes sense, but functionality wise thosee cells behave so much like mini web pages that UIWebView just naturally springs to mind.